# error in suds-jurko setup command: use_2to3 is invalid

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

enviroment info:
python3 --version:Python 3.6.5
pip3 --version:pip 21.2.4

when i execute : "pip3 install -r requirements.txt" there is a error:error in suds-jurko setup command: use_2to3 is invalid

Answer (score 20):

Based on comments [here](https://github.com/andersinno/suds-jurko/issues/6), I was able to install this package using

```
pip install "setuptools==58.0.0"
pip install -r requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Answer (score 2):

The 2to3 error is an error thrown to cover up another error.  To find out the real error, you have to build from source.

1.Download source: https://pypi.org/project/suds-jurko/#files

2.Compile:

```
unzip suds-jurko-0.6.zip
cd suds-jurko-0.6
python setup.py install
```

I don't remember the 'real' error I received, but here is the solution:

1.Create Symlinks from /lib to /local/lib:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6
ln -s /usr/lib64/python3.6 /usr/local/lib64/python3.6
```

2.Probably not best practice.. give permission recursively:

```
chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

3.Install setuptools

```
pip3 install --user "setuptools==58.0.0"
```

4.Install suds-jurko using regular pip and not pip3.  Also install without root privileges.

```
su -c "python -m pip install suds-jurko --user" YOURUSERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a community fork of `suds-jurko`. It is releasing packages under the main suds package name

Details: [suds-commutity](https://github.com/suds-community/suds)